# force close when provider change to GPS_PROVIDER

Tags: android, location

i try get curent coordinate and addres with NETWORK_PROVIDER in trhead, but when i change to GPS_PROVIDER, the app force close: with the message from LogCat :

> 02-24 16:54:00.249: E/AndroidRuntime(3004):
>   android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

I think what the difference is when I just change the provider from  Network to GPS, as before when using a network, application is running well..

this is the code for thread :

```
private void requestPosition()
    {
        if(!cekInternet())
        {
            Txt_konek.setText("Need internet Connection");
        }
        else
        {
            new Thread()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    Message localMessage = Message.obtain();
                    localMessage.what=1;
                    try
                    {
                        Splash2.this.ll = Splash2.this.show_current_location();
                        Splash2.this.lat = Double.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(Splash2.this.ll.substring(0,Splash2.this.ll.indexOf(",")-1)));
                        Splash2.this.lng = Double.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(Splash2.this.ll.substring(1+Splash2.this.ll.indexOf(","))));
                        Splash2.this.posisiUser = Splash2.this.goToGeocoder(Splash2.this.lat.doubleValue(), Splash2.this.lng.doubleValue());
                        Splash2.this.messageHandler.sendMessage(localMessage);
                        return;
                    }
                    catch(Exception localException)
                    {
                        while(true)
                        {
                Splash2.this.Txt_konek.setText("no internet connection");                           
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .start();
        }
    }
```

this method for get current location :

```
private String show_current_location()
    {
        Location localLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(localLocation==null)
        {               
            this.longLat = localLocation.getLatitude()+","+localLocation.getLongitude();
        }
        else
        {
            this.longLat = localLocation.getLatitude()+","+localLocation.getLongitude();
        }
        return this.longLat;
    }
```

and this is locationListener :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPS provider takes time to get a fix and you are processing your `show_current_location` method before that, so you are getting the error. You need to wait until you receive lat and lang

Comment: yerp...GPS take a more long time then using a network..and the solution ti fix this issue?
-thx- :)

Comment: Yes, GPS is more accurate than network provider, but GPS drains more battery and require more time to get a fix, you should use it wisely with network provider

Comment: i hope my lecturer have a wise think as u have.. but he just considering the accuracy without considering the others..so to finish my last project ..he still request using the GPS. i can't reject request's so i try to using gps from my previous code that using a network..

Comment: Good! if this answer helped you then please mark it as accepted (click on a right mark on left of my answer), so that it can help others.

Comment: One solution might be, you start a countdown timer for 10-15 sec and check if you receive the fix within that or else show an alert with "taking more time to get the location, retry"

Comment: how could? im starting with android earlir this month, so many thinks i havent know yet

Answer (score 0):

if your location localLocation is null then a null pointer exception will be thrown at

```
 localLocation.getLatitude()
```

Comment: i try to fill the coordinate manually when localLocation is null and its running, but stil cannot get the current location using GPS, or i should do this with Asynctask??